# Error when I try to close the shiny's app window while the app is running

Tags: r, shiny

*I have this shiny app and its logic is very clear.Whenever i press the Hit button it prints 1000 hi.The problem is that if I go and close the app window while it is printing it crashes.How can i solve it?*

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("h","hit")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
   observeEvent(input$h,{
      for(i in 1:1000){
        print("hi")
      )
   })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: As far as I understand, closing the app window means an end to the app, so how does the error concern you? Is it that you are taking some user inputs from the app window, and then resume the original procedure?

Comment: Yes when i close the app window i want the app to stop. So if i close the window before i press the hit button or after the loop has finished the app ends normal. But if i close the window while it is printing it crashes. So i want to avoid such an error but i don't know how to handle it. And for you last question the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Does it do the trick for you?

```
tryCatch({shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)})
```

Comment: I get this when i close the window:Called from: print.default("hi")
Did you run it and it worked?